# Uncaught ReferenceError in DevTools for global variables

Tags: javascript, devtools, referenceerror

#### Update:

Looks like by importing another JS file and using the ES6 Modules, devtools compiles a bit different (will need to dive into learning more). The variables I thought were global were not in the module. Was able to fix this by assigning them to:

```
window.variable_name = variable_name
```

This allowed me to call the variables from devtools.

---

I have a project I am working on to practice a few JS skills. For the most part I have everything up and running but have come across an issue I can not seem to remedy.

I have an app.js file that is linked in my index.html. When running the live server from VS code everything works as it should, but when I open devtools to check some of the variables (global) & functions I get "Uncaught referenceError: *variable_name* is not defined" with a VM#:# reference.

Up to today, I have been able to call the variables from console without a problem.

I have 12 global variables, and all but 1 (submit) have this issue.

App.js:

```
import { autocomplete } from "./autocomplete.js";

// ######## GLOBAL VARIABLES ############
//------- Selectors ----------
const container = document.querySelector('.search-container');
const searchElement = document.getElementById('search');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('input[name="search-bar"]');
const submit = document.getElementById('search-bar');
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');
const results = document.querySelector('.results');
const resetButton = document.querySelector('.reset');
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error');
const heart = document.querySelector('#favorite');

//------- Arrays & Objects ----------
let names = [];
let pokemon = {};
let bgImages = ["./resources/images/forest_background.jpg", "./resources/images/field.jpg", "./resources/images/galar-scenery.png", "./resources/images/night.jpg", "./resources/images/training.jpg", "./resources/images/poke-background.webp"];


//########## Grab & Store Pokemon Names for Autocomplete ##########
async function loadPokeNames() {

    try {
        const response = await fetch ('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=250');
    
        if (response.ok) {
          const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        //   console.log(jsonResponse)
            for (const poke of jsonResponse.results){
               names.push(poke.name);
            }
        }
        // throw new Error('Request Failed!')
    
    } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
}

//############ Search Function ###############
async function searchPokemon(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let pokeSearchValue = e.srcElement[0].value.toLowerCase();
    searchElement.hidden = true;
    loader.hidden = false;
    
    
    try {
        const pokeResponse = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeSearchValue}`);
        if (pokeResponse.ok) {
            const pokeJSON = await pokeResponse.json();

            // Assign Values to Pokemon Object
            pokemon.name = pokeJSON["name"];
            pokemon.img = pokeJSON["sprites"]["other"]["official-artwork"]["front_default"];
            pokemon.hp = pokeJSON["stats"][0]["base_stat"];
            pokemon.attack = pokeJSON["stats"][1]["base_stat"];
            pokemon.speed = pokeJSON["stats"][5]["base_stat"];
            pokemon.defense = pokeJSON["stats"][2]["base_stat"];
            pokemon.special_attack = pokeJSON["stats"][3]["base_stat"];
            pokemon.special_defense = pokeJSON["stats"][4]["base_stat"];

            console.log(pokemon);
            createPokeCard(pokemon);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Something Went Wrong.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        loader.hidden = true;
        errorMessage.hidden = false;
        resetButton.hidden = false;
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}

// ####### Generates the Pokemon Card #########
function createPokeCard(object) {
    const pokeName = document.querySelector('#poke-name p');
    const pokeHP = document.querySelector('#hp');
    const pokeImg = document.querySelector('#poke-image img');
    const pokeAttack = document.querySelector('#attack .num');
    const pokeSpeed= document.querySelector('#speed .num');
    const pokeDefense = document.querySelector('#defense .num');
    const pokeSpecialA = document.querySelector('#special-attack .num');
    const pokeSpecialD = document.querySelector('#special-defense .num');
    const backgroundImage = document.querySelector('#poke-image')

    // Assign values to Results Card

    backgroundImage.style.backgroundImage = `url('${bgImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]}')`;
    pokeName.textContent = object.name;
    pokeHP.textContent = `${object.hp} HP`;
    pokeImg.src = object.img;
    pokeAttack.innerText = object.attack;
    pokeDefense.textContent = object.defense;
    pokeSpeed.textContent = object.speed;
    pokeSpecialA.textContent = object.special_attack;
    pokeSpecialD.textContent = object.special_defense;

    setTimeout(() => {
        loader.hidden = true;
        results.hidden = false;
        resetButton.hidden = false;
    }, 3000)
    

}

// ####### Resets Search & Card #########
function resetSearch() {
    searchInput.value = '';
    resetButton.hidden = true;
    results.hidden = true;
    searchElement.hidden = false;
    errorMessage.hidden = true;

    for (const att in pokemon){
        delete pokemon[att];
    }
}

//######## Favorite Functions ###########
function hoverFav() {
    this.src = '../resources/images/heartline-fill.png';
}
function hoverOutFav() {
    this.src = '../resources/images/heartline.png';
}


// ########### EVENTS ##############
window.onload = loadPokeNames;
autocomplete(searchInput, names)
heart.addEventListener('mouseenter', hoverFav);
heart.addEventListener('mouseout', hoverOutFav);
resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetSearch);
submit.addEventListener('submit', searchPokemon);
```

Linked (correct path) script tag:
 `<script src="./script/app.js" type="module"></script>`

Any help or a point in the right direction would be amazing.

Tried calling global variables from devtools. Got an uncaught referenceError message.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe the `type="module"` has something to do with it.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli after removing the import in the app.js and the module type in the index, I am able to call those variable/functions. It must have to do with the way devtools compiles the modules? 

Still learning, so not 100% sure if that is the reason, but seems like it is the culprit.

Comment: I have added an explanation to the behavior above, I also wouldn't recommend adding variables to the global window object, they might overwrite already existing variables or get overwritten by 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I have made a bit of digging around and it turns out the reason this happens is indeed because you're setting the type of the script as a module. Scripts that are run as modules are under strict mode by default, thus they don't allow access to global variables.

Also, they are made to run as a separate scripts(modules) and so any variables defined or imported into them are private by default and are not accessible to the global scope.

As for the error, in normal standard JS scripts, the access of a variable not defined properly(without let/const) will not throw an error, under strict mode however, it converts it into an error and throws it.

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) for more info on differences between standard & module scripts. Also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_modules) for info on strict mode.